# How can I decrease the size of Ratingbar?

Tags: android, rating-system

In my activity I have some Rating bars. But the size of this bar is so big!
How can I make it smaller?

**Edit**

Thanks to Gabriel Negut, 
I did it with the following style:

```
<RatingBar
style = "?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
android:numStars = "5"
android:rating   = "4" />
```

Now, the size is reduced but number of stars and rating do not take effect!!!
Why? I have 7 stars that 6 of them is selected.

Comment: Do you mean a Seekbar? Setting height and width works fine for me. Can you post your code snippet here?

Comment: I would recommend removing the "edit" and instead making it the accepted answer. That or @GabrielNegut can edit his answer to include that kind of solution. Including the solution in the question kind of takes away from the Q&A experience.

Comment: `style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"` works for me.

Answer (score 215, accepted):

The original link I posted is now broken (there's a good reason why posting links only is not the best way to go). You have to style the `RatingBar` with either `ratingBarStyleSmall` or a custom style inheriting from `Widget.Material.RatingBar.Small` (assuming you're using Material Design in your app).

Option 1:

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
    ... />
```

Option 2:

```
// styles.xml
<style name="customRatingBar"   
    parent="android:style/Widget.Material.RatingBar.Small">
    ... // Additional customizations
</style>

// layout.xml
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    style="@style/customRatingBar"
    ... />
```

Comment: or using this style style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall" will reduce the size.

Comment: But there is a useless extra padding on the right! How to remove that?!

Comment: Note: make width="wrap_content" to get rid of extra stars

Answer (score 107):

This was my solution after a lot of struggling to reduce the rating bar in small size without even ugly padding

```
 <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/listitemrating"
        style="@android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleX=".5"
        android:scaleY=".5"
        android:transformPivotX="0dp"
        android:transformPivotY="0dp"
        android:isIndicator="true"
        android:max="5" />
```

Comment: Scale bothers alignment of sibling views and imbalances margins and spacing.

Answer (score 68):

If you want to show the rating bar in small size, then just copy and paste this code in your project.

```
  <RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/MyRating"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/getRating"
    android:isIndicator="true"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="0.1" />
```

Comment: What is android:stepSize="0.1" ?

Comment: http://codingaffairs.blogspot.com/2016/05/android-material-design-small-rating-bar.html

Comment: also check my asnwer at the end of this page.

Comment: @HammadTariqSahi It is good, keep it up, But is there any problem in my code? Let me know if there is any thing, please

Comment: @PirFahimShah thankyou, bro I havent checked this code. you can improve and can style rating bar if you follow that approach.

Comment: @HammadTariqSahi Ok, i will surely look at it

Comment: @can you please fix this issue  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37383165/tokenmismatchexception-for-api-in-laravel-5-2-31

Comment: @PirFahimShah what if I want the ratingBarStyleSmall style AND also I want to style the stars' color to yellow please?

Answer (score 50):

The below snippet worked for me to resize the ratingBar

```
<RatingBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"
    android:scaleX=".5"
    android:rating="3.5"
    android:scaleY=".5"
    android:transformPivotX="0dp"
    android:transformPivotY="0dp"
    android:max="5"/>
```

[image]

Comment: how to change the ratting bar color for this rating bar half fill, full fill, and empty color ?

Comment: rating parameter is used to fill the rating bar right? I used android:rating="3.5" so 3.5 stars are filled. you can set up to 5 because max = 5 is set in the xml.
If you want to change the colors of the rating bar, you have to create a style in style.xml see this link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/35914622/2915785

Comment: how to android:transformPivotX="0dp"
    android:transformPivotY="0dp" Programmatically ?

Comment: @NaveedAhmad But there is a useless padding on the right! How to remove that?!

Comment: @Mr.Hyde check the styles of raringbar https://stackoverflow.com/a/24407907/2915785

Comment: @NaveedAhmad It doesn't do any related thing to padding! Or at least, I couldn't find it. https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles_material.xml   ->  `progressDrawable`, `indeterminateDrawable`, `minHeight`, `maxHeight`.

Answer (score 46):

You can set it in the XML code for the `RatingBar`, use `scaleX` and `scaleY` to adjust accordingly. "1.0" would be the normal size, and anything in the ".0" will reduce it, also anything greater than "1.0" will increase it.

```
<RatingBar
  android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:scaleX="0.5"
  android:scaleY="0.5" />
```

Comment: the problem with this is that the ratingbar still takes up the same width and height as before even though the icons are smaller. This causes alignment issues since there is a bunch of left and right padding next to the first and last icons. For example, if you want your icons like this "XXXXX", after the scaling it will look like this "-----XXXXX-----" where the "-" is empty space and "X" is an icon. So your rating bar will seem like it got pushed to the right because of the empty space

Comment: Im guessing you're using relative layout. Its a pain but you can tweak it to go into the right position by using  `android:layout_marginRight  `and the likes to get it the way you want.

Comment: to get scale without creating a padding on the left  add android:transformPivotX="0dp"

Answer (score 12):

[Working Example](http://codingaffairs.blogspot.com/2016/05/android-material-design-small-rating-bar.html)

```
             <RatingBar
                style="@style/RatingBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:numStars="5"
                android:rating="3.5"
                android:stepSize="0.5" />
```

and add this in your styles xml file

```
<style name="RatingBar"   
parent="android:style/Widget.Material.RatingBar.Small">
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/primary_light</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/primary_dark</item>
</style>
```

This way you dont need to customise ratingBar.

Answer (score 10):

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874537/how-to-make-a-smaller-ratingbar/49875703#49875703). Best way to achieve it.

```
 <style name="MyRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
   <item name="android:minHeight">15dp</item>
   <item name="android:maxHeight">15dp</item>
   <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
   <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/home_add</item>
</style>
```

and use like

```
<RatingBar
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:isIndicator="false"
      android:max="5"
      android:rating="3"
      android:scaleX=".8"
      android:scaleY=".8"
      android:theme="@style/MyRatingBar" />
```

Answer (score 8):

This Worked for me.
[image: Check this image]

```
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:scaleX=".8"
            android:scaleY=".8"
            android:stepSize="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.543"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/title"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 8):

This will work perfectly

```
style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
```

Answer (score 7):

```
<RatingBar
  style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you arrived at the solution?

Comment: This doesn't allow `RatingBar` to get changed.

Answer (score 6):

In the `RatingBar` tag, add these two lines

```
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small"
android:isIndicator="false"
```

Answer (score 5):

In `RatingBar` give attribute:

```
style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar`, you have 2 styles to use; `Indicator` and `Small` for large and small sizes respectively. See example below.

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/rating_star_value"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small"
    ... />
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Rating bar in Linearlayout with weightSum. Please make sure that you should not assign the layout_weight for rating bar. Instead, that place rating bar inside relative layout and give weight to the relative layout. Make rating bar width wrap content.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/userRating"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:stepSize="1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 <RatingBar     android:id="@+id/id_tv_rating_bar"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_80sdp"
                android:numStars="5"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:rating="5" />
```

Just use `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small"` it'll work for Sure!

Comment: after using this rating bar color is not changing. How to change it?

Answer (score 2):

If you only need the default style, make sure you have the following width/height, otherwise the numStars could get messed up:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: using this style style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"  will reduce the size

Answer (score 0):

For those who created rating bar programmatically and want set small rating bar instead of default big rating bar

```
    private LinearLayout generateRatingView(float value){
        LinearLayout linearLayoutRating=new LinearLayout(getContext());
        linearLayoutRating.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        linearLayoutRating.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        RatingBar ratingBar = new RatingBar(getContext(),null, android.R.attr.ratingBarStyleSmall);
        ratingBar.setEnabled(false);
        ratingBar.setStepSize(Float.parseFloat("0.5"));//for enabling half star
        ratingBar.setNumStars(5);
        ratingBar.setRating(value);
        linearLayoutRating.addView(ratingBar);
        return linearLayoutRating;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <RatingBar
                    android:id="@+id/ratingBarDisplay"
                    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:numStars="5"
                    android:scaleX="1.3"
                    android:scaleY="1.3"
                    android:transformPivotX="0dp"
                    />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).