# How can I change color of specific layout component?

Tags: android

How can I change color of star components in this [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z93hx.png)?
Can it be done it below code or do I have to work in xml?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(R.style.Custom);
    ViewGroup layout = getLayout(getIntent().getStringExtra("key1"));
    if (layout == null) return;
    layout.addView(new ProgressBar(this));
    layout.addView(new RadioButton(this));
    layout.addView(new RatingBar(this));
    layout.addView(new CheckBox(this));
    layout.addView(new Switch(this));
    layout.addView(new SeekBar(this));
    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3333ff"));
    layout.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000);
    setContentView(layout);    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: Change color of ratingbar to golden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32810341/android-change-color-of-ratingbar-to-golden)

Comment: There's some older answer too, but I guess the newer one is valid in 2020. The old one: [Android RatingBar change star colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446270/android-ratingbar-change-star-colors/17369705)

Comment: Problem for me is that  RatingBar etc are added with code, they are not there in layout design. How can I acces those variables?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a reference of your layout components:

```
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private RadioButton radioButton;
private RatingButton ratingButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(R.style.Custom);
    ViewGroup layout = getLayout(getIntent().getStringExtra("key1"));
    if (layout == null) return;

    progressBar = new ProgressBar(this);
    radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
    ratingButton = new RatingButton(this);

    layout.addView(progressBar);
    layout.addView(radioButton);
    layout.addView(ratingBar);

    progressBar.setBackgroundColor(...);
    radioButton.setBackgroundColor(...);
    ratingButton.setBackgroundColor(...);   
    //And so on, with the appropriate method for each View

    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3333ff"));
    layout.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000);
    setContentView(layout);   
}
```