# Rating bar with custom size

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to display rating bar with my custom size. But in the case that rating bar with my custom size, the stars disappear in my layout. Can I manage the size of padding and margin the rating bar?

```
 <RatingBar
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:id="@+id/rating_order"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:numStars="5"
                    android:stepSize="1.0"
                    android:scaleX="0.3"
                    android:scaleY="0.3" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a smaller RatingBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874537/how-to-make-a-smaller-ratingbar)

Comment: also see [How can I decrease the size of Ratingbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153587/how-can-i-decrease-the-size-of-ratingbar)

Comment: It's not exactely the same because he do it with his custom icons and he don't want just to decrease the size

Comment: @motis10 in the above link there is an answer for that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to set the parameters from styles:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="CustomRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar" >
 <item name="android:numStars">5</item>
 <item name="android:stepSize">1.0</item>
 <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
 <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
 <item name="android:paddingBottom">44dp</item>
 <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">4dp</item>
 <item name="android:layout_marginTop">4dp</item>
  </style>
<resources />
```

And then in your `RatingBar` add a style:

```
style="@style/CustomRatingBar"
```

Comment: Thank you. You gave me the way to find my hopeful answer. I just change the style parent to @android:style/Widget.Material.RatingBar.Small . That makes my problem. Thank you so much sir.

Comment: DO you know how i can programatically set the size of each star or a specific star, say the 3rd one from 5 stars?