# How to display rating value(Integer) from an API (Google api) using ratings bar in Android (preferably using Kotlin)?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

```
 val rating = jsonObject.getInt("rating")
```

for instance, a rating of 4, to be displayed as 4 stars in my view.

I am looking for ways to display it programatically as  image views or to use Ratingsbar

Comment: ratingbar.setNumStars(rating);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `RatingBar`, in your view:

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

In your Activity:
Use `synthetic` Just type the id of your `RatingBar` and it'll get your `RatingBar`

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.your_activity.*

val rating = jsonObject.getInt("rating")
ratingBar.numStars = rating
```

or just old school:

```
val rBar: RatingBar = findViewById(R.id.ratingBar)
rBar.numStars = rating
```

> **Edit:** As you wanted to know about resizing:

```
<RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="5"
        android:rating="3.5"
        android:scaleX=".5"
        android:scaleY=".5"
        android:transformPivotX="0dp"
        android:transformPivotY="0dp" />
```

You can use `scaleX` & `scaleY` to resize accordingly (chose a balanced value of both) the base value is 1 for both. (.5,.5 will make it half of the original size.)

Here's a question about resizing: [How can I decrease the size of Ratingbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153587/how-can-i-decrease-the-size-of-ratingbar)

Comment: Hi, do you know how I can change the size of the stars? I tried to use style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small" but it is not working