# Problem in reducing size of Rating Bar.

Tags: android, android-widget, rating

I want to reduce the size of the Rating bar, I got some style properties that do it, but they are out of the reach of user interaction they are just Indicator. So, please let me know how to reduce the size. Thanks in advance.

Comment: refer this link may serves your requirements http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874537/how-to-make-a-smaller-ratingbar/6882182#6882182

Answer (score 26, accepted):

How to glue the code given [**here**](http://kozyr.zydako.net/2010/05/23/pretty-ratingbar/)  ...

**Step-1. You need your own rating stars in `res/drawable` ...**

[image: A full star]

[image: Empty star]

**Step-2 In `res/drawable` you need `ratingstars.xml` as follow ...**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+android:id/background"
          android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/secondaryProgress"
          android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/progress"
          android:drawable="@drawable/star" />
</layer-list>
```

**Step-3 In `res/values` you need `styles.xml` as follow ...**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="foodRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/ratingstars</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">22dip</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">22dip</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Step-4 In your layout ...**

```
<RatingBar 
      android:id="@+id/rtbProductRating"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:numStars="5"
      android:rating="3.5"
      android:isIndicator="false"
      style="@style/foodRatingBar"    
/>
```

Try Activity ....

```
package x.y;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class RatingBarDemo extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.product);

    }
}
```

With this layout `product.xml` ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="5dip"
    android:paddingBottom="5dip">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgProduct"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip" 
        android:src="@drawable/icon" 
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layProductInfo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgProduct"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="0dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip">  
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvProductName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Product Name"
            android:textSize="17dip" 
            />
        <RatingBar 
            android:id="@+id/rtbProductRating"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:rating="3.5"
            android:isIndicator="false"
            style="@style/foodRatingBar"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvProductName"
            />  
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPriceLabel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="$45.87"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/rtbProductRating"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvProductName"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:textSize="17dip" 
            />  
      </RelativeLayout>     
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you do not actually need the half star image.

Comment: If I use rating bar this way then rating star images are being stretched at below side. What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: AFAIK There is a limitation of platform that rating stars will not be scaled automatically, so the size of drawables for rating stars must be same with maxHeight and maxWidth.

Answer (score 0):

I've searched through a lot of posts with the same question here and I was trying out the answer provided by [@Vaibhav A. Jani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/703851/vaibhav-a-jani), when I just stopped by a more simple solution to this question. I am not saying that [@Vaibhav A. Jani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/703851/vaibhav-a-jani) answer is not correct tho.

Try this, it worked for me to see stars much smaller:

```
RatingBar ratingBar = new RatingBar(context, null, android.R.attr.ratingBarStyleSmall);
```

And also I was able to create lots of RatingBar dynamically, without touching any xml file, just java coding.

[***Reference***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14669882/how-to-dynamically-set-the-style-to-ratingbar-in-order-to-create-custom-seekbar)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing style

```
 <RatingBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:rating="4.5"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Working Code :**
*You can easily reduce size of rating bar stars* 
**Just add in xml as below**

### android:scaleX="0.5" android:scaleY="0.5"

```
  <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar_visibility"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:scaleX="0.5"
            android:scaleY="0.5" />
```