# How to dynamically set the Style to RatingBar in order to create Custom SeekBar in Android

Tags: android

Through layout.xml it is working.

```
<RatingBar 
  android:id="@+id/hotel_rating_bar"
  style="@style/custom_ratingbar" />
```

But i want to set the style Dynamically.

Any Answer will be highly appreciated...

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607610/how-to-change-the-star-images-of-the-ratingbar

Comment: But i am looking for Dynamic setting the Style to RatingBar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamically changing the style of views at runtime is not yet supported in Android, except for `TextViews` via [setTextAppearance](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextAppearance%28android.content.Context,%20int%29).

You have to set the style before the view gets drawn,
either via XML or via Java in the constructor.

```
RatingBar ratingBar = new RatingBar(context, null, android.R.attr.ratingBarStyleSmall);
```