# Adding RatingBar to ListAdapter using Simple Adapter not working Correctly

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a ListAdapter in my android application... I am trying to add a ratingBar to each item in the list with its value set to a value that is contained in [TAG_RATING]. The problem is that the list is showing and the only ratingBar is being stuck at the very bottom of the list and is rather large.

Please see the below code:

```
   ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllProductsActivity.this, productList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_BID,
                                TAG_NAME,
                                TAG_RATING},
                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name, R.id.ratingBar});
                    ((SimpleAdapter) adapter).setViewBinder(new MyBinder());
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
```

then the ViewBinder class looks like this:

```
   class MyBinder implements ViewBinder{
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data, String textRepresentation) {
        if(view.getId() == R.id.ratingBar){
            String stringval = (String) data;
            float ratingValue = Float.parseFloat(stringval);
            RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) view;
            ratingBar.setRating(ratingValue);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the list item xml file looks like this:

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<!-- Name Label -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:textSize="17dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

  <RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/rating"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:stepSize="0.25"
    android:numStars="5"
    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RatingBar` widget should be placed in the list row layout that you use in the adapter, `R.layout.list_item`. Right now, you just placed a `RatingBar` widget below the `ListView` in the main layout.

Comment: Yep that was it but my rating bars are huge... IsIndicator="True" is what I am using but they are still big...

Comment: @Skindeep2366 You should post the row layout file. If you remove the `isIndicator` attribute is the `RatingBar` smaller?

Comment: Removing the isIndicator attribute does not affect the size of the RatingBar

Comment: @Skindeep2366 Set the width of the `RatingBar` to `wrap_content` to see only those 5 stars. Then you could use `?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall` to make it smaller(add `style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"`).

Comment: Again than you for the help.. I am totally new to java let alone coding for android.. I have a strong vb background but the change is killing me.

Comment: @Skindeep2366 Well, does it work? You could also use `?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator` as a style. The widget isn't quite perfect, see this question for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874537/how-to-make-a-smaller-ratingbar

Comment: Working great... Have a bit of a layout problem where the stars are all on the line under the name instead of the same line...

Comment: @Skindeep2366 If you want them on the same line then set the orientation of the `LinearLayout` to `horizontal` and the width of the *name* `TextView` to `wrap_content`. Of course this will place that gone `TextView` on the same line but I don't know what you want to do with it. Also make sure you have room on a single line for both the `TextView` and the `RatingBar`.

Comment: searching now on how to get only the first 20 char's of the name string before sending them to the listadapter.. Thanks much on the insight..

Comment: @Skindeep2366 Use the same `ViewBinder` and if the view's id is `R.id.name` substract a substring from the `data` parameter which is at most 20 characters long.

Comment: Got it all sorted out now... Thanks for the recommend on using the ViewBinder to manage that..