# Android: Strange border RatingBar

Tags: android, xml, styling, stroke, ratingbar

Currently I'm developing an app which uses the `RatingBar`. I accidentally changed some styling values and now my `RatingBar` has some kind of stroke on it.

[1 http://qs.lc/3ns3n](http://qs.lc/3ns3n)

Like this.

I know this is a really silly question but I just can't remove it haha. Thank you!

```
<RatingBar android:layout_width="146dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
    android:id="@+id/card_main_inner_ratingbar"
    android:stepSize="1" android:numStars="10" />
```

Comment: I can't see your code

Comment: @donfuxx http://pastebin.com/QuQbvjS6

Comment: take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874537/how-to-make-a-smaller-ratingbar

Comment: Use CTRL + Z until you reach where you were before you screwed it up.

Comment: @donfuxx That is not going to help me. I already use the smaller layout.
Can't undo anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by setting the `layout_width` and the `layout_height` with only `wrap_content`

Answer (score 0):

Create a selector file in the drawable folder:

custom_ratingbar_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/star_off" />

 <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/star_off" />

 <item android:id="@android:id/progress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/star_on" />

</layer-list>
In the layout set the selector file as progressDrawable:

 <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_ratingbar_selector"
        android:numStars="8"
        android:stepSize="0.2"
        android:rating="3.0" />
```

And that's all we need.

Answer (score 0):

If it was the same case for you just use:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRatingBar
   ...
   android:secondaryProgressTint="YOUR_COLOR_HERE"/>
```

**Before**:
[image]

**After:**
[image]