# Issue styling Rating bar

Tags: android, ratingbar

I am having problem styling rating bar

Here is the screenshot

[image]

I want to reduce the size of rating bar. I know I can use style small to make them smaller but that is too small. Can I make somewhat medium style?.

Here is my xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#F0EEEF">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="RATE OUR SERVICES"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="By Quality"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
    <RatingBar
        android:theme="@style/RatingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:isIndicator="false" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="By Services"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    <RatingBar
        android:theme="@style/RatingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:isIndicator="false" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="By Time"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    <RatingBar
        android:theme="@style/RatingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:isIndicator="false" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Overall Rating"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    <RatingBar
        android:theme="@style/RatingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:isIndicator="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Instead of wrap_content for layout_widht and layout_height, put your size desired in dp. (e.g 150dp for layout_width)

Comment: rating bar gets cropped when giving height width in dp

Comment: I think that the RatingBar is too static.....see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874537/how-to-make-a-smaller-ratingbar

Answer (score 2):

You Can use a custom RatingBar. Following is the code 
1. create a file in drawable as custom_ratingbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:id="@android:id/background"
android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty" />
 <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty" />
 <item android:id="@android:id/progress"
android:drawable="@drawable/star_full" />
</layer-list>
```

then use following in your RatingBar :-

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_ratingbar"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="0.2"
    android:rating="3.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom style for ratingbar to make it have suitable size:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="foodRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
        <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item> <!-- your desired size -->
        <item name="android:maxHeight">48dip</item> <!-- your desired size -->
    </style>  
</resources>
```

then use this style to your rating bar.
There is more specific tutorial:http://kozyr.zydako.net/2010/05/23/pretty-ratingbar/.

Answer (score 0):

I made a custom ratingbar which might help you: [SimpleRatingBar](https://github.com/FlyingPumba/SimpleRatingBar).

It features:

- Fully working `android:layout_width`: it can be set to `wrap_content`, `match_parent` or abritary dp.
- Arbitrary number of stars.
- Arbitrary step size.
- Size of stars can be controlled exactly or by setting a maximum size.
- Customizable colors (border, fill and background of stars).
- Customizable size separation between stars.
- Customizable border width of stars.
- Allows to set OnRatingBarChangeListener
- Stars fill can be set to start from left to right or from right to left (RTL language support).
- AnimationBuilder integrated in the view to set rating programatically with animation.

[Here is a preview of it](https://github.com/FlyingPumba/SimpleRatingBar/raw/master/images/sample.gif).

You can find it either in `jcenter` or in `Maven Central`. So in your `build.gradle` file just add to your dependencies:

`compile 'com.iarcuschin:simpleratingbar:0.1.+'`

I hope it's useful.

Comment: Will definitely give it a try next time as that project is over now