# Why rating bar's onRatingBarChangeListner dose not work?

Tags: android, ratingbar

I am trying to add `rating bar` in my code. I am using `onRatingBarChangeListner` to get the values of rating bar. But `rating bar` is not responding at all. It dose not get selected or change color.

```
public class SurveyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements getQuestionsAsyncTask.GetQuestions,RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener{

private ArrayList<Question> mQuestionsArrayList;
private TextView mTextQuestion1,mTextQuestion2;
private RatingBar ratingbar1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_survey);

 //   addListenerOnButtonClick();

    mTextQuestion1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textQuestion1);
    mTextQuestion2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textQuestion2);

    Button next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_next);

    final RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.MyRating);

   next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            float rating=ratingBar.getRating();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your Selected Ratings  : " + String.valueOf(rating),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         //   startActivity(new Intent(SurveyActivity.this,UserDetailsActivity.class));
        }
    });



    mQuestionsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    getQuestionsAsyncTask getQuestionsAsyncTask = new getQuestionsAsyncTask(this,this,mQuestionsArrayList);
    getQuestionsAsyncTask.execute();
}
public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                            boolean fromUser) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your Selected Ratings  : " + String.valueOf(rating),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Tried this but dose not work.

```
    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/MyRating"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:isIndicator="true"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="0.1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textQuestion2"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

Also tried this [tutorial](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/ratingbar/android-rating-bar-example/)

What's going wrong? Can anyone help please? Thank you..

**EDIT**: Tried both the answers still it's not working:

```
public class SurveyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements getQuestionsAsyncTask.GetQuestions,RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener{

    private ArrayList<Question> mQuestionsArrayList;
    private TextView mTextQuestion1,mTextQuestion2;
    private RatingBar ratingbar1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_survey);

        Button next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_next);

        final RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.MyRating);
        ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(this);


       next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                float rating=ratingBar.getRating();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your Selected Ratings  : " + String.valueOf(rating),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float v, boolean b) {

            v = ratingBar.getRating();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Selected Ratings  : " + String.valueOf(v), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `onRatingChanged` should be as follows

```
@Override
public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float v, boolean b) {

}
```

Also add `setOnRatingBarChangeListener` on your `ratingBar`

```
ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(this);
```

**Edit 1** : For Toast try following

```
String rating=String.valueOf(ratingBar.getRating());  
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rating, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**Edit 2** : You are not able to change rating because of `isIndicator` property. As per android's documentation

> android:isIndicator   Whether this rating bar is an indicator (and
>   non-changeable by the user).

so remove that property and change your `ratingBar` to following

```
<RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/MyRating"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="0.1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textQuestion2"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

Also why I removed line

```
style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
```

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3173594/1157879)

Comment: not toast. Rating bar's stars dose not get selected. @indramurari

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to set the Change listener on the ratingBar view,

```
final RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.MyRating);
ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(this);
```